# Validating/Inserting text into new window with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I've searched everywhere for many different ways of inserting text into a newly opened window with javascript within a function, yet none have seemed to work which leads me to believe I'm missing a key fundamental ingredient here.

```js
function validate2() {
  var valTxt = document.webPage.txt2.value;
  if (valTxt == null || valTxt == "") {
    alert("Field cannot be empty!");
    return false;
  }
  if (valTxt.length < 5) {
    alert("You must enter at least 5 characters!")
    return false;
  }
  myWin = window.open('mypopup.html', "mywin", '');
  myWin.getElementById('userText').innerHTML = valTxt;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Exercise 3</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <form name="webPage" action="http://thebest404pageever.com/">
    Please type anything over 5 characters: <input type="text" name="txt2"><br/>

    <input type="submit" name="b2" value="Confirm" onClick="return validate2()">
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

I have an empty HTML file for mypopup with just a h1 element with the id userText. The popup certainly shows up, but continuously shows blank. Is there anything I'm missing here? Thanks a lot.

```js
myWin = window.open('mypopup.html', "mywin", '');
  
  window.onload=function placeText(){
  myWin.getElementById('userText').innerHTML = valTxt;
```

I appended it with this, and it doesn't look right and sure enough, doesnt work right either.

Comment: take the 'placeText' out... Try putting it as is indicated in my answer.  `window.onload = function() { ... }`

Comment: I tried that the first time and yeah, didn't work either, I only tried the placeText trying to figure out if that was the case. This problem has taken me 6 hours to figure out, crazy.

Answer (score 0):

The loading of the new window is done asynchronously. As indicated in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open):

> Note that remote URLs won't load immediately. When window.open() returns, the window always contains about:blank. The actual fetching of the URL is deferred and starts after the current script block finishes executing. The window creation and the loading of the referenced resource are done asynchronously.

You will need to defer your changes to the DOM until after they are loaded.

I would use a window.onload handler for this:

```
window.onload=function() {
  myWin.getElementById('userText').innerHTML = valTxt;
};
```

Comment: Thanks ras, but I'm not sure how I can even start go about fixing this haha, do you have an idea on where I could start looking into?

Comment: I would try using a window.onload handler. Put this right after you do your .open statement.

Comment: very sorry to keep nagging but I'm desperate at this point to understand. so I have it like this now